# C# - String.Format()

Tags: c#, string

I'm new to C#. Can anybody explain the following lines:

```
        string value = "";
        string tempValue = "=Fields!{0}.Value";


        value = RemoveSpace(ReportDataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName);
        value = String.Format(tempValue, value);
```

Comment: Documentation for `string.format()` can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-format

Comment: I suggest reading up on [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 5):

You need to read about [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) which replaces each format item in a specified string with the text equivalent of a corresponding object's value.

`RemoveSpace` would be some method like [**Trim()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx) to remove the space around the string.

Answer (score 1):

you are formatting the `value` according to `tempValue` format, where {0} is place holder
for more info on string format [see this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)

Comment: thanks.
at line 3, `value` gets some values.
at line 4, `value` formated according to `tempvalue`
at line 5, how to get tha value which holds at line-5 ???

Comment: @user1010399: suppose u have another string s, then s=value

Comment: @user1010399: simply use that value

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want this line to be explained:

```
value = String.Format(tempValue, value);
```

[String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) creates strings from a pattern and values. It is a static method in the C# language. It receives a format string that specifies where the following arguments should inserted. The format string uses substitution markers.

So `string.Format` replaces the "{0}" in this string `"=Fields!{0}.Value"` with your value.

**Side-note:** you can (should) always consult MSDN first. Just type the method into google and the first link is probably  the documentation.

Comment: Thanks @Tim. I have issue at line 4 as you explained. BTW at line 4, the `value` is supposed to contains a string value `myValue`, and I wanted to compare the value e.g. `if(value == "myValue")` it should return `true` but fail to do so.

Comment: @user1010399 you are assigning different value to the `value` in third line.

Comment: at the third line, it reads from the XML file which is different every time.